# LINQ error on select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am writing this LINQ to EF query to get a matching item.

```
if (user.UserID > 0)
{
    var TempUser = (from c in GSData.tblUsers
                    where c.UserID == user.UserID
                    select c).First();
                    ..........
```

The value of user.UserID at runtime is 579 and there is a matching row. However i get the error

```
{"This property cannot be set to a null value."}
System.Data.ConstraintException was unhandled by user code
```

Further it breaks surprisingly at place where middle name is set. It happens to be a field in tblUsers database with nvarchar(20) and the value is null.

```
 _MiddleName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
```

However i had written similar queries for getting matching items and they work fine. I am just selecting and not updating any values. So i have been breaking my head over why this is happening. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: where is user.UserId?

Comment: user object is passed to the function having the query. userid is a field in user object

Comment: If you're seeing that on a select then it suggests that your EF and database constraints are not in sync.

Comment: @Carth. I doubted that and did update model from database again. Wouldn't that sync EF and db constraints as well? I checked the EF model now. Middle name properties are same. nullable and max length of 20

Comment: I've had problems in the past where "minor" changes like altering a data type length, changing not null constraints, etc. weren't picked up by refreshing the EF. In those cases I had to edit the EF manually or rebuild the EF. I would validate that it is indeed throwing an error due to that condition and then go check the EF generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the table in your entity model, then choose update from database. EF won't pick up nullable/non-nullable changes just by updating an already existing table.